# Why does my method override give a type clash?

Tags: java, junit, liskov-substitution-principle

I need help to understand how the testing should go through. I should implement the test method in `Stacktest.java` (have already done that). Then extend `StackTest` with `LinkedlistTest` (I have already done that). Then add super.setUp() as the first line in `LinkedListTest.setUp` (I have done that).

But the one overriden method is `getIntegerStack` that I implement in the `LinkedListTest`, but then I get an error:

```
'getIntegerStack()' in 'LinkedListTest' clashes with 'getIntegerStack()' in 'StackTest'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

I dont know how to fix it. The code:

- `StackTest.java` is an abstract test class.
- For each implementation of `Stack`, one may simply extend `StackTest` with an implementing test class. The only method that should be overridden is `StackTest.getIntegerStack`, which should simply return an instance of a class that implements `Stack<Integer>`. See the `setUp` method in `StackTest` and try to understand how this works.
- In your case, you should extend `StackTest` with a test class called `LinkedListTest`.
- you must add a call to `super.setUp()`; as the first line in `LinkedList.setUp()`.

TODO: How should I make the `getIntegerStack()` do work.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Test class for LinkedList
 */
public class LinkedListTest extends StackTest{

    /* A sequence of integers */
    private int[] elements;

    /* An empty linked list */
    private LinkedList<Integer> list;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        elements = new int[]{-919,  388,   67, -248, -309, -725,  904,   53,
                90, -469, -559,  256,  612,  366, -412, -221,
                347, -921, -978,  324, -858,  480, -443,  891,
                329,   -5,  878, -538,  445, -366,  760,   52};
    }

    /**
     * This is the only method that implementing classes need to override.
     *
     * @return An instance of Stack.
     */
    @Override
    protected Stack<Integer> getIntegerStack() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Stack interface:

```
  * A interface of stack
  */
 public interface Stack <T> {
     /**
      * Adds the element to the top of the stack.
      */
     void push (T elem);
    
      T pop();

      T top();

     int size();

     boolean isEmpty();
 }
```

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
/**
 * A singly linked list.
 *
 */
public class LinkedList<T> implements Stack <T> {
    private ListElement<T> first;   // First element in list.
    private ListElement<T> last;    // Last element in list.
    private int size;  // Number of elements in list.

    /**
     * A list element.
     */
    private static class ListElement<T>{
        public T data;
        public ListElement<T> next;

        public ListElement(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given element at the beginning of this list.
     *
     * @param element An element to insert into the list.
     */
    public void addFirst(T element) {
        ListElement<T> firstElement = new ListElement<>(element);
        if (this.size == 0){
            this.first = firstElement;
            this.last = firstElement;
        }
        else{
            firstElement.next = this.first;
            this.first = firstElement;
        }
        this.size ++;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given element at the end of this list.
     *
     * @param element An element to insert into the list.
     */
    public void addLast(T element) {
        ListElement<T> lastElement = new ListElement<>(element);
        if(this.size ==0){
            this.first = lastElement;
        }
        else{
            this.last.next = lastElement;
        }
        this.last = lastElement;
        this.size ++;
    }

    /**
     * @return The head of the list.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty.
     */
    public T getFirst() {
        if (this.first != null){
            return this.first.data;
        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return The tail of the list.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty.
     */
    public T getLast() {
        if(this.last != null){
            return this.last.data;
        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an element from a specified index.
     *
     * @param index A list index.
     * @return The element at the specified index.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of bounds.
     */
    public T get(int index) {
        if(index < 0|| index >= this.size){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else{
            ListElement<T>element = this.first;
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                element = element.next;
            }
            return element.data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first element from the list.
     *
     * @return The removed element.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty.
     */
    public T removeFirst() {
        if(this.first != null || this.size != 0){
            ListElement<T> list = this.first;
            this.first = first.next;
            size --;
            if(size() == 0){
                last = null;
            }
            return list.data;
        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes all of the elements from the list.
     */
    public void clear() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.size =0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the element to the top of the stock.
     * @param elem
     */
    @Override
    public void push(T elem) {
        ListElement <T> list = new ListElement<>(elem);
        if( first == null){
            first = list;
            last = first;
        } else{
            list.next = first;
            first = list;
        }
        size ++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the top element in stack,
     * that is the element that was last added.
     * Throws an EmptyStackException if stack is empty.
     * @return the top element in the stack.
     */
    @Override
    public T pop(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }else{
            ListElement <T> list = first;
            first = first.next;
            size --;

            return list.data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns the top element in the stack without removing it.
     * Throws an EmptyStackException if stack is empty.
     * @return the top element.
     */
    @Override
    public T top() {
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }else{
            return first.data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the stock
     * @return The number of elements in the stock.
     */
    public int size() {

        return this.size;
    }

    /**
     * Note that by definition, the list is empty if both first and last
     * are null, regardless of what value the size field holds (it should
     * be 0, otherwise something is wrong).
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if this list contains no elements.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return first == null && last == null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a string representation of this list. The string
     * representation consists of a list of the elements enclosed in
     * square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the
     * characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to
     * strings by the method toString() inherited from Object.
     *
     * Examples:
     *  "[1, 4, 2, 3, 44]"
     *  "[]"
     *
     * @return A string representing the list.
     */
    public String toString() {
        ListElement<T> listOfElements = this.first;
        String returnString = "[";
        while(listOfElements != null) {
            returnString += listOfElements.data;
            if(listOfElements.next != null){
                returnString += ", ";
            }
            listOfElements = listOfElements.next;
        }
        returnString += "]";
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Abstract test class for Stack implementations.
 *
 * Implementing test classes must only implement the getIntegerStack
 * method. Be careful not to override ANY other methods!
 *
 */
public abstract class StackTest{
    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5);

    private Stack<Integer> stack;
    private int[] valuesInStack;
    private int initialStackSize;
    private Stack<Integer> emptyStack;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        valuesInStack = new int[] {3, 4, 1, -123, 4, 1};
        initialStackSize = valuesInStack.length;
        stack = getIntegerStack();
        pushArrayToStack(valuesInStack, stack);
        emptyStack = getIntegerStack();
    }

    /**
     * Push an array to the stack, in order.
     *
     * @param array An int array.
     * @param stack A Stack.
     */
    private void pushArrayToStack(int[] array, Stack<Integer> stack) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            stack.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the only method that implementing classes need to override.
     *
     * @return An instance of Stack.
     */
    protected abstract Stack<Integer> getIntegerStack();

    @Test
    public void topIsLastPushedValue() {
        // Arrange
        int value = 1338;

        // Act
        emptyStack.push(value);
        stack.push(value);

        int emptyStackTop = emptyStack.top();
        int stackTop = stack.top();

        // Assert
       assertThat(emptyStackTop, equalTo(value));
     assertThat(stackTop, equalTo(value));
    }

    // HELPERS

    /**
     * Pops the desired amount of elements.
     *
     * @param stack A Stack.
     * @param amountOfElements The amount of elements to pop.
     */
    private void popElements(Stack<Integer> stack, int amountOfElements) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfElements; i++) {
            stack.pop();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class used for stream operations when both actual and expected values
     * need to be gather in conjunction.
     */
    private class ResultPair<T> {
        public final T actual;
        public final T expected;

        public ResultPair(T actual, T expected) {
            this.actual = actual;
            this.expected = expected;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The return type for `StackTest.getIntegerStack()` and `LinkedListTest. getIntegerStack)` in your code is `Stack<Integer>` in both cases. So I doubt this code gives the error message you provide. Maybe you can double check the code in the question is the same as the code giving the error message?

Comment: I checked and the code is have i have wrote it down. This is why I dont know what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkedList test extends StackTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913603/linkedlist-test-extends-stacktest)

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinkedListTest` class contains the erroneous line:

```
import java.util.Stack;
```

Because of that, the `getIntegerStack()` method returns a `java.util.Stack` object instead of an object of the `Stack` interface you created yourself.

Just dropping that import statement will fix your problem.

Unrelated to your problem, you can also let `getIntegerStack()` return any subclass of your `Stack` interface. In this case it would be more natural to let it return your `LinkedList`:

```
/**
 * In the context of `LinkedListTest` we return a `LinkedList`.
 *
 * @return An instance of Stack.
 */
@Override
protected LinkedList<Integer> getIntegerStack() {
    return new LinkedList<Integer>();
}
```